# Can I specify in Visual Studio that my program looks for a file in the same file location that the .exe is?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.0, directory

A feature in my program requires files from a folder. I would like to know if it is possible to specify that the folder will be in the same directory as the .exe for the program (so if the user changes the directory during install, it's changed within the program automatically)..

So, for example, if the .exe is in "C:/Program Files/MyProgram", the program will automatically look for "C:/ProgramFiles/MyProgram/MyFile"? And if the .exe is in "D:/MyStuff/MyProgram", the program will automatically look for "D:/MyStuff/MyProgram/MyFile"?

[image: Specify File Path]

I would like to specify here that it looks in the same location as the .exe is located..

Is this possible?

Comment: `.\dic\en-GB.dic` will probaly do the trick

Comment: @Grumbler85 If you make this an answer I'll choose it. :)

Comment: @Toby It won't work always

Comment: Why so? What will stop it working?

Answer (score 1):

Perhapse in code you can modify that propery with the value of: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Comment: Or Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. However, I used @Grumbler85's answer as it was the most simple and it worked.

Comment: @Toby It doesn't work. It relies on the working directory being the same as the directory in which the executable is stored. That will not always be the case.

Comment: Okay. I'll have a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to exert control over the working directory in a GUI app. The working directory may not be the directory which contains the executable. Or the working directory may have been changed by some code in your process. And since relative paths are relative to the working directory, this makes any attempt to use relative paths something of a lottery.

So, my advice is that you use an absolute path. Use Path.Combine to join together the path that contains your executable (for example by using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) and the filename, and use that resulting absolute path.